# Change the naming style in Resharper from a config file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper, naming-conventions

Is there any issue to write the "Naming Style" rules in a file and then load them in Resharper ??

We are a team of 9 C#/.Net Developers and we are searching if it's possible ! Because it will take too much time if we have to do it manually from Resharper settings, in each computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correcly, but it seems you want to share your ReSharper settings among team members.

ReSharper allows saving settings per solution, which you can then check into your source control repository. That should allow all users to use the same settings.

When you edit the ReSharper settings (ReSharper > Options), at the bottom there should be a button called "Save To". There you can choose to save your settings to a solution-wide file, which can then be checked in.